# transaction isolation level in @Transactional

Tags: quarkus

In Quarkus, is there a way to configure transaction isolation level when using @Transactional?

I'm aware that I can configure it per session, but I would like a per transaction configuration just like in Spring (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

Comment: No there is no way to change the isolation level via annotations, as Quarkus is exposing the API from the Transaction specification in Java EE; please open a feature request and possibly describe the use case in detail?

I wasn't aware that this was possible in Spring and I suspect that implementing it comes with several limitations and compromises - we'll need to think about it carefully.

Comment: @Sanne ok thanks, that's what I saw while diving in the code, the Java EE exposes basically only the transaction timeout. I will open a feature request. In the meanwhile I'm executing a "set transaction isolation level serializable" in a native query at the beginning of my transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus doesn't handle this for now so I changed the transaction isolation level manually:

```
Panache.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("set transaction isolation level serializable read write").executeUpdate();
```